# Why isn't the infinite scroll not working?

Tags: tumblr

Is there something wrong with the theme code?
here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=f0AQb9vs
thank you :)

Comment: 1.  You should post your code here in case Pastebin goes offline.  2.  You should *really* narrow down your code to be [the most minimal, working example](http://sscce.org) that still causes your frustration.